# How to execute this sql query using criteria in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have a sql query

```
delete from response where r_id in (1,2,3,4) and u_id='10';
```

Now I want to execute this queru using hibernate.

I know i can do this through `createSQLQuery` but I have to use criteria.

How i can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use criteria here, you will have to fetch all the objects to Java and delete them using Java mechanisms.

This approach is **very** slow in terms of performance, but IFF you really must use it:

```
List<Response> doomedResponses =  createCriteria(Response.class).addRestriction(/* restrictions here*/).list();
for(Response doomed : doomedResponses) {

     entityManager.remove(doomed);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need  to add two restrictions, one for IN, here is the java api for Restriction.in

> **static Criterion**   in(String propertyName, Object[] values) 
>             Apply an "in" constraint to the named property

So your code should look like this

```
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Yourclass.class);
// create a collection for IN values comparision and lets assume it is called CollectionofValues
       criteria.add(Restrictions.in(r_id, collectionofValues);
      criteria.add(Restriction.eq(u_id,'10'));
```